# Is this function deprecated in Doctrine 2 synchronizeWithArray()

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am moving from Doctrine 1 to Doctrine 2.

And am using this function `synchronizeWithArray()` in Doctrine 1 and need to use it in Doctrine 2 .. Is this function exist in Doctrine 2 or any equivalent function ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you noticed this discussion? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/Vw9kYhuMB24

Comment: Yes, did .. but it's not solve the issue ... is not do what synchronizeWithArray() do!!